# CXF Rest with Maven and tomcat

Tags: spring, rest, maven, tomcat, cxf

I try to get my first rest application up and running in tomcat. I use maven for the build process. Build works without any errors.

Tomcat extract the rest.war without raising an error and I try to request http://hostname:8080/rest/categoryservice/category/01. This leads to a 404 response. I enclosed my web.xml, beans.xml and a snippet of the service class. The pom contains only the dependencies. I hope you have any suggestions or hints to find out the mistake.

service class:

```
@Path("/categoryservice")
@Produces({"application/json","application/xml"})
public class CategoryService {
    @GET
    @Path("/category/{id}")
    @Produces({"application/json","application/xml"})
    public Category getCategory(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    ...
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />


<jaxrs:server id="categoryRESTService" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="categoryService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>


<bean id="categoryService" class="demo.restful.CategoryService">
    <property name="categoryDAO">
        <ref bean="categoryDAO" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I assume there is a category with id "01" - otherwise, try http://hostname:8080/rest/categoryservice/category/1 - Is there any stacktrace on the tomcat console? Pls post here if so.

Comment: Thanks spring dependency was missing. But I have another question. I would like to see the wadl file. I there something I have to add? hostname:8080/rest/categoryservice?_wadl returns nothing, also hostname:8080/rest?_wadl

Answer (score 0):

This URL should hit your service:
http://hostname:8080/rest/categoryservice/category/1

This URL should return a _wadl
http://hostname:8080/rest/categoryservice?_wadl

This URL should return a list of available services
http://hostname:8080/rest/categoryservice/

Normally I give something more concrete to my url-pattern example:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/restapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In this case, This URL should return a list of available services
http://hostname:8080/rest/restapi/categoryservice/